# Python, Pandas: Using isin() like functionality but do not ignore duplicates in input list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to filter an input dataframe (`df_in`) against a list of indices. The indices list contains duplicates and I want my output df_out to contain all occurrences of a particular index. As expected, `isin()` gives me only a single entry for every index.

How do I try and not ignore duplicates and get output similar to `df_out_desired`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_in = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(4), data={'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[10,20,30,40]})

indices_needed_list = pd.Series([1,2,3,3,3])

# In the output df, I do not particularly care about the 'index' from the df_in
df_out = df_in[df_in.index.isin(indices_needed_list)].reset_index()
# With isin, as expected, I only get a single entry for each occurence of index in indices_needed_list

# What I am trying to get is an output df that has many rows and occurences of df_in index as in the indices_needed_list
temp = df_out[df_out['index'] == 3]

# This is what I would like to try and get
df_out_desired = pd.concat([df_out, df_out[df_out['index']==3], df_out[df_out['index']==3]])
```

Thanks!

Comment: show the actual outputs that you want to see so we can understand better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `reindex`

```
df_out_desired = df_in.reindex(indices_needed_list)
df_out_desired 
Out[177]: 
   A   B
1  2  20
2  3  30
3  4  40
3  4  40
3  4  40
```

Comment: it doesn't work if your ```indices_needed_list``` array contains negative numbers.